# Should I use ctx.translate for an endless game-map?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Well, just imagine you keep going up but your player stays put in the middle, and as you go up the map generates itself randomly.

With the help of:

```
ctx.translate(0, 1);
```

the map moves towards you as you move up.

now, I have a few methods in mind and of them is ctx.translate, but I have a few questions:

1) in the long run, what I fear is that it will keep the memory of the previous drawings once they go out of the canvas borders and eventually the ctx x/y system will go to numbers as high as millions.

2)I need something which is CPU friendly. I am just not sure what ctx.translate does under the hood exactly, does it behave in the likes of ctx.clearRect and then redraws everything?

3) anything better to achieve the same thing will be lovely, I already know about the old clearRect(which is heavy) and redraw method, just looking for other options.

EDIT: the player may change his X coordinate in some position too.

Comment: 1. `ctx.translate` can do anything it wants to 'under the hood' as long as it conforms to the API (and is likely implemented differently from browser to browser), and 2. Have you tried actually coding it before asking?

Comment: [`translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate) only modifies the underlying matrix. You still have to redraw things. So it's pretty "CPU friendly". If the level is randomly generated and moving down as the player moves up, why not just change the positions of the environment and not the player? No translate required. Then, assuming you can't go down, just remove them after the leave the screen.

Comment: As for 3) You're not going to get away from redrawing. You will *always* have to redraw. The trick is finding out how much you *actually* have to redraw. For example, don't attempt to render things which are off of the canvas or if only a chunk of the screen is changing, just render over that. If you can get away with just drawing on top of the old image instead of clearing it, do it.

Comment: Guys, I know I have to redraw things. but with ctx.translate I will perhaps have to draw only the new things + the player itself, not the old ones as the old ones get carried away with ctx.translate which supposedly behaves better.

Comment: @user1938653 I'm telling you, `ctx.translate` isn't going to alleviate any of your rendering problems. If you're going to continue trying to draw things which aren't visible then it may make it a little bit faster but the "right" solution is to not draw them at all. `ctx.translate` will not change what you have to draw. Literally, you can think of it as just applying an offset to all of your objects positions. If you translate by 5 in both directions, it would be equivalent for you to do `ctx.drawImage(img, x + 5, y + 5)`

Comment: @user1938653 [Here's an ultra stripped down version](https://jsfiddle.net/dhrercfo/) of what I'm talking about. Create objects just before they're on screen, destroy them once they're off-screen. Clearing the whole screen really isn't that expensive. Only try to avoid it if you're hitting performance problems.

Comment: **Fun fact:** there is indeed a limit to which translate works correctly. I don't really know what is happening under the wood, and the strangest thing is that both chrome and FF has the exact same behavior, but when setting an offset > 70,000,000 on my machine, it starts to have some troubles https://jsfiddle.net/5boxyvw9/